# Laravel5.1 404.blade.phpで変数を使用する方法

Tags: php, laravel

routes.phpでルートを設定していないURLへアクセスされた際、/views/errors/404.blade.phpを表示させようと思っていますが、
Controllerを通すことは可能でしょうか？

その404.blade.phpの中で、Controllerから渡した変数（例えばログインユーザ名の表示など）の表示をしたいです。

Answer (score 1):

404.blade.phpでログインユーザ名を表示したいだけならば、
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
とすればOKです。

しかし、テンプレートにそれら以外の変数を渡したいのであれば、
app/Exceptions/Handler.php を編集します。

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;//7行目あたりに追加
```

```
protected function renderHttpException(HttpException $e)//Handlerクラスに追加
{
    $status = $e->getStatusCode();
    $var = "あいうえお";
    if (view()->exists("errors.{$status}")) {
        return response()->view("errors.{$status}", ['exception' => $e,'var'=> $var], $status);
    } else {
        return $this->convertExceptionToResponse($e);
    }
}
```

vendor/laravel/framework/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php
にある親クラスで行っている処理をオーバーライドしています。